# JNDI GlobalNamingResource loading order

Tags: tomcat, jndi, server.xml

In my server.xml I have the following:

```
<Resource name="secrets-server"
      auth="Container"
      type="linux.socketipc.IPCServer"
      factory="SecretsVaultServerFactory" />



<!-- IDM Datasource for portal -->
<Resource name="idm_portal"
    auth="Container"
    factory="db.DataSourceWrapper"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxLifetime="600000"
    connectionTimeout="30000"
    dataSourceClassName="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    maximumPoolSize="145"
    minimumIdle="145"
    dataSource.url="jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234/plf_idm?ssl=true"
    dataSource.user="plf" />
```

The Datasource wrapper class depends on the SecretsVaultServerFactory being loaded first by tomcat so that it can perform a context look-up and use the SecretsVault object within it:

```
        SecretsVault sv = (SecretsVault) nameCtx.lookup("secrets-server");
```

The issue is that the JNDI GlobalNamingResources appear to be getting loaded out of order. Or I'm just not aware of how the ordering is controlled.

If the DataSourceWrapper resource is loaded before the secrets-server, then I get the following error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [secrets-server] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [secrets-server].
```

Which makes sense because it hasn't been loaded yet. Is there a way to force JNDI to load my secrets-server resource first before any other global naming resources are loaded?

Comment: Do you have resource-refs for these?

Comment: Nope - I think I would only need that if I was defining them in context.xml or web.xml

Comment: I was wondering if it does them by resource-ref order. Just a thought.

Comment: So I dug into the code, it looks like it loads everything into a hash map then turns the hash map into an array. Because of this, the order is unknown (elements in a Hash map are stored unordered. So I think when loading out of order if a name lookup fails, it just tries again later making this not an issue